# Passing data to ui via event handler in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, events, windows-phone-8, event-handling, eventargs

I'm using the following pattern to pass response data of an HTTP request(runs on a worker thread) to the concerning UI.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Counter c = new Counter(new Random().Next(10));
            c.ThresholdReached += c_ThresholdReached;

            Console.WriteLine("press 'a' key to increase total");
            while (Console.ReadKey(true).KeyChar == 'a')
            {
                Console.WriteLine("adding one");
                c.Add(1);
            }
        }

        static void c_ThresholdReached(object sender, ThresholdReachedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The threshold of {0} was reached at {1}.", e.Threshold,  e.TimeReached);
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
    }

    class Counter
    {
        private int threshold;
        private int total;

        public Counter(int passedThreshold)
        {
            threshold = passedThreshold;
        }

        public void Add(int x)
        {
            total += x;
            if (total >= threshold)
            {
                ThresholdReachedEventArgs args = new ThresholdReachedEventArgs();
                args.Threshold = threshold;
                args.TimeReached = DateTime.Now;
                OnThresholdReached(args);
            }
        }

        protected virtual void OnThresholdReached(ThresholdReachedEventArgs e)
        {
            EventHandler<ThresholdReachedEventArgs> handler = ThresholdReached;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, e);
            }
        }

        public event EventHandler<ThresholdReachedEventArgs> ThresholdReached;
    }

    public class ThresholdReachedEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public int Threshold { get; set; }
        public DateTime TimeReached { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When I debug the code, I observed that event is sent to it's receiver UI succesfully,but with empty data. I also monitored that data is put correctly to the event just before the event is sent. Seems like data is disappeared on the fly.

Any ideas?

---

Ok here is my code;

Step 1: In the UI's background worker I do the following;

```
    private void ButtonSend_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Create a worker thread
        worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(worker_DoWorkFinished);
        worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    ....


    void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {

         ApplicationManager.Instance.getHTTPManager().makeHTTPSRequest(url);

    }
```

Step 2: Then in the HTTPManager, after the WebClient finishes it's POST request I do the following;

```
            webClient.WriteStreamClosed += (s, args) =>
            {
                if (args.Error != null)
                {
                    status = mStatusFromServer;
                }
                else
                {
                    status = HTTPManager.mDefaultStatus;
                }

                ContactSendCompletedEventArgs args2 = new  ContactSendCompletedEventArgs();
                args2.Status = status;
                Debug.WriteLine("Status: " + args2.Status);
                OnContactSendCompleted(args2);
                //Debug.WriteLine("Status: " + status);
                //Contact_Send_Complete(this, status, i);
            };
```

I also did the event handling in this class like;

```
 namespace MyPhone8App.Common
 {

public delegate void ContactSendCompletedEventHandler(ContactSendCompletedEventArgs e);

class HTTPManager
{

    ...

    protected virtual void OnContactSendCompleted(ContactSendCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler<ContactSendCompletedEventArgs> handler = ContactSendCompleted;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler<ContactSendCompletedEventArgs> ContactSendCompleted;
}     

public class ContactSendCompletedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public String Status { get; set; }
}
```

Final Step: Back in UI I do the following;

```
        HTTPManager man = ApplicationManager.Instance.getHTTPManager();
        man.ContactSendCompleted += c_Contact_Send_Completed;

    static void c_Contact_Send_Completed(object sender, ContactSendCompletedEventArgs args)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("The status: ", args.Status);

        ...

    }
```

And that's all. Any ideas?

Comment: You should post the code with the problem of your winphone 8 app.

Comment: Sorry but it'n not available now. But for now I can detail what I did more clearly.    

I have a UI Page that triggers BackgroundWorker in which I perform an HTTPS request using WebClient inside MyHTTPManager class. (This class is where I defined my EventHandler as well.)

In UI Page I subscribe to the event like;

       ApplicationManager.Instance.getHTTPManager().My_Event +=     Event_Handler_CallBack_In_Page.

In Weblient OpenWriteClosed() method, I get the status of the response and passing it to the UI. Although it enters the callback,no data semmed to be passed.

Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: Define "empty data." Is the parameter `e` null?

Comment: No, not at all. Please see my answer